# How to show wifi launcher in Xfce

Tags: raspbian

I have just installed Xfce in preference to LXDE on my Raspbian RPi 3 and it works as expected. The desktop panel doesn't show anything related to Wifi or Bluetooth (as LXDE does). How do I go about adding these launchers to my panel?

Comment: I think those are part of PIXEL (or were part done by the same people for the Pi before the LXDE->PIXEL fork), and DE widgets are not inter-operable.

Comment: I just entered `sudo apt-get install wicd-gtk` for the wireless indicator, and `sudo apt-get install blueman` for the Bluetooth indicator.

Comment: **Sounds like I was wrong :)**  If this worked for you please leave an answer of your own (unfortunately you may be required to wait 24 hours).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple solution was to apt-get install the necessary software and restart my system. In this case `wicd` and `blueman` did the trick.

[image]

Comment: While this may have "solved" your particular problem, you have **NOT** restored the launchers. `wicd` is a different network manager from the default `dhcpcd` and AFAIK incompatible (although they share some config files).